# jquery hover a div and display image on another div with effect

Tags: jquery, html, image, hover, preview

OK javascript newbie here, I want help!

Here is the design that explains better the situation.

[**My JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1tL17bbr/1/)

My Code:

```
<div class="design">
<div class="menu">5 menu options will be in this div and when we hover at each link an image must appear to the right with fast zoom in effect like shooting.
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">menu option</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">menu option</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">menu option</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">menu option</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">menu option</a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="zoom-preview">image will appear here when we hover at each link at the left. each link it's own image. Also there must be a default image here when we do not hover at any link at the left.</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

All I want to do is when we enter the page there will be a default image at right.
But when we hover at each link at the left, the image on the right will be replaced with another image, with a fast zoom effect like shooting for example.

When no link is hovered the default image will be again displayed.

Please some help with the javascript code.. Thanks!

Comment: there isn't even any javascript in your fiddle. Have you looked that the jquery documentation? There is an event called hover. You could trigger that and do whatever you want. Try it out then come back and ask.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: I know I deserve this answer.. you are right I will check it out and try, if you can provide any other help will be very appreceated. Thanks!

Comment: Once you provide what you have tried, we can help you. Without that, you are expecting us to do the code for you, and that will get you nothing.

Comment: ok up until now I managed to make the default image disappear and appear at mouse enter and mouse leave http://jsfiddle.net/1tL17bbr/5/ now I have to find out how to show the alternative image when I hover each menu item

Comment: @Lola when I click a link it should go to the link's url, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick demo that will get you started:

**Demo**:[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z82yu9j1/)

As you can see I'm using a list with data attributes to set which image should be displayed ( `<li data-image='image.jpg'><a ...></a></li>`) - the rest is handled by JS.

To control the behavior change the variables value as needed:

```
var imageContainer = '.img_container', //selector of the image container
    imageList      = '.hoverimage',     //selector of the image list
    maxWidth       = 'parent',          //parent or specific CSS width. 
    defImage       = 'image_to_display.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6ywtk6u/

You will need to put a source for the images

Jquery:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(".zoom-preview").html($(this).html());
  },
  function() {
    $( ".zoom-preview" ).html( "image will appear here when we hover at each link at the left. each link it's own image. Also there must be a default image here when we do not hover at any link at the left." );
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="design">
<div class="menu">5 menu options will be in this div and when we hover at each link an image must appear to the right with fast zoom in effect like shooting.
           <li class="menu-item">
               <a href="#"><img alt="foo"/></a></li>
           <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="#"><img alt="bar"/></a></li>
          <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="#"><img alt="bam"/></a></li>
          <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="#"><img alt="baz"/></a></li>
          <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="#"><img alt="quux"/></a></li>
       </div>
       <div class="zoom-preview"> 
       original content
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
```

on hover enter, you take the html inside the link and put it in the display box. when it leaves, you put the original content back.