# jquery hover a list item and display image in another div, list is dynamic

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html-lists, thumbnails

I have a Wordpress test site and am using a plugin to list recent posts of a certain category, with thumbnails from the posts. I'd like to change it so that instead of each item in the list displaying a thumbnail next to it, only the item that is being hovered over shows its thumbnail, in a separate div.

I like one jquery solution I found at the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041921/jquery-hover-a-div-and-display-image-on-another-div-with-effect) by Shlomi Hassid. However, I can't adapt it, because he's using static images and the 'data-image' variable, which is not present in the list I'm working with. (His gives a fiddle example.)

It seems like I need to pass the data-image variable to the PHP to make it work, so I tried adding this to Hassid's script:

```
var htthumb = $(this).data('image');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://testsite.humortimes.com/wp-content/plugins/recent-posts-widget-thumbs-mine/includes/widget.php',
        data: {'variable': htthumb},
    });
```

...and in the PHP added `$htimgsrc = $_POST['htthumb'];`

Then, in the list class, added `data-image=$htimgsrc` before the PHP segment that creates the list:

```
<li class="ht-menu-item" data-image=$htimgsrc <?php
```

But the result just shows the data-image prefix as above with the variable name, not the source information that I need it to.

So, I guess I just need help with passing the variable from the js to the php, or an altogether different way to do this.

The page I'm working on, in a test site, [is here](http://testsite.humortimes.com/).

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I've been rethinking this. I really only need the attachment image url placed it after "data-image=' for the js to find the image, so I don't need to get the variable from the js as above. So, during the 'have posts' loop in the plugin, I tried to grab the image url using `wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb_id )`, where $thumb_id is a variable from another PHP file in the plugin that is grabbing the thumbnail's id. This way, I figure, I can get the correct image. But that seems to return null for some reason.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please post code samples you are working on and show us what have you tried so far. refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Made the edit as requested.

Comment: I've been rethinking this. I really only need the thumbnail image url, so I don't need to get it from the js. But I tried some things in the PHP that so far have not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, gave up on trying to get the image attachment info from within the plugin (although that should be possible, since in its original form, it supplies the thumbnail next to each item on the list; but I wanted it in a separate div, and only while hovering over the list item). I decided I just needed to get the image's url with my own function. So, I found some useful code and adapted it, inserting this in the loop, and using the '$htthumb1' variable produced for the 'data-image=' url:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    } else {
        // No post thumbnail, try attachments instead.
        $attachment = get_children(
        array(
            'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'numberposts'    => 1,
        )
    );
    if ( ! is_array( $attachment ) || empty( $attachment ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $attachment = current( $attachment );
    $htthumb1 = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID );
    };
```